# Is it possible to change color for Edge's endArrow?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

I'm getting into draw.io and trying to understand whether it's possible to set color not for the whole `Edge` but only for the `endArrow` or `startArrow`. Is there a style property for this?

Comment: No, not currently.

Comment: Thanks @David! Is there a feature request for this already? :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no feature request at the moment.

Regards,